# Conflict between styles.css and @media query.css

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have this sample html/css code.

```css
div a {width:20%; display:inline-block; height:100px; color:#000; background:red; padding: 10px; text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>A</a>
  <a>B</a>
  <a>C</a>
</div>
```

When using media queries to adjust the padding of the anchor tag it is still okay when using such media like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:960px)
{
    div a {width: 25%; padding: 15px;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px)
{
    div a {width: 27%; padding: 15px 10px;}
}
```

But when I use such media with specific ranges of the width:

```
@media only screen, (max-width:769px) and (max-width:959px)
{
    div a {padding: 10px 21px 19px 10px;}
}
```

Why does this media query conflicts with my style css when I adjust the padding? Does my declaration of media query to set specific ranges of width is incorrect?? If so, what's the proper way of calling specific width (769px-959px).

I'm new to media queries, please help.

Comment: You target a range with `min` and `max`, like this `@media only screen and (min-width:769px) and (max-width:959px)` ... and drop the comma you have in the rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ranges that you have specified that they overlap each other,i change 959 to 1000 for better result.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:768px)
{
    div a {background-color: blue;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width:769px) and (max-width:959px)
{
    div a {background-color: pink;}
}
 @media only screen and (min-width:959px) and (max-width:1000px)
{
    div a {background-color: red;}
}
```

```html
 <div><a href="">goooood</a></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This actually should be pretty simple luckily, should I be reading this right. If you're trying to set a range where your *minimum* device width is 769px and your maximum is 959px, you should write your code as so:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 959px) { div a { padding: 10px 21px 19px 10px; } }
```

Hope this works!